# struct padding network compatibility c++

Tags: c++, networking, struct, padding

I have been researching into game networking and am confused by the issue of struct padding. I understand that different compilers add padding to structs where they see fit, and this may mean more bytes are sent in a networking stream than desired.

However, surely this will not affect the program. Once the compiler has build the .exe that struct format will be set, and so there should be no issues with translating a received packet as the format will be the same?

Comment: As long as there's only one supported platform, that's true.

Comment: If you use the same compiler and same version of it, for all programs involved then it won't be a problem. However, if you ever change compiler or even compiler version it *may* be an issue. You can however tell all modern compilers to "pack" structures so they don't have padding.

Comment: No problem, if if both sides of networking communication are compiled with the same structure padding. I think that it is a good idea to specify padding explicitly for a structure which is sent through network. BTW, there is also endianless issue...

Comment: And on the issue of networking, don't forget different CPU endianess too. If everything is running x86 windows, compiled with MSVC you are unlikely to have to worry about any of this. If you are mixing OSes and CPU's I'd suggest writing out data members one by one and using a normalised format for endianess.

Comment: Make serialize functions that output each data member correctly into a stream and a deserialize function to remake the struct on the other end. That's the only safe way which won't bite you in the backside later on.

Comment: I have used htons and co. for the endian issue.
I have created 2 functions for packing and unpacking data which take variable no. of args using cstdarg which works fine, it just seems a little unnecessary to me when you could just put a struct straight into the stream?
@JoachimPileborg How to I tell the compiler to "pack" a struct?
Thanks guys

Comment: For GCC (gcc or g++) use `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` (see the [online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html)). For Visual C++ you use [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx).

Comment: Ok guys, I have decided to just use packing and unpacking functions because apparently packing is generally dis-advised and causes problems, according to the majority of forums. Thanks anyway though